# Avoid starting debugging from the beginning

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible to set a starting point for the debugger so that every debugging session
will start **immediately** from that point (instead of starting from the beginning of the code)?

Or to express it differently:
Isn't it possible to somehow store everything until the breakpoint so that next time the debugger could just instantly resume to that specific breakpoint (instead of starting from the beginning of the code and pausing at the breakpoint)?. Is there any debugger that can do this?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a breakpoint at a line that you want to inspect.

You have a description how to do it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You could attach a debugger to a running process, but i'm afraid that it will be on a random place of execution. You could make a wait for a key or button press in your code and attach to your program before continuing.

Comment: Thanks. But this will **start** debugging from the beginning of the code. I want to **start** from the breakpoint, not from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Debugger in visual studio.

In your code, click on the line number, you will see a dot on the line.

When you run the program, it will 'pause' at the line you specify, you can then walk through your program line by line from there

Answer (score 0):

No. It would have to run the code up to the point you want to get all the variables etc in the right state. If you just set a breakpoint where you're interested from and hit `F5` it should get there quickly enough.
If it doesn't get there quickly enough, jot down the variables used and make some unit tests round the troublesome functions instead. That will skip the 10 minutes.

Comment: The problem is that it takes about 10 minutes to reach the breakpoint.What you say is true...or it could somehow store all the values and next time it could just resume to that breakpoint (instead of going all the way from the start to the breakpoint). Is there any debugger that can do this?

Comment: Oh bad luck - you should have said the the question.